# Hibernate Search with Lucene Phone Number Analyzer issues

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

Our database contains thousands of numbers in various formats and what I am attempting to do is remove all punctuation at index time and store only the digits and then when a user types digits into a keyword field, only match on those digits. I thought that a custom analyzer was the way to go but I think I am missing an important step...

```
@Override
protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName) {

    log.debug("Creating Components for Analyzer...");
    final Tokenizer source = new KeywordTokenizer();
    LowerCaseFilter lcFilter = new LowerCaseFilter(source);
    PatternReplaceFilter prFilter = new PatternReplaceFilter(lcFilter,
            Pattern.compile("[^0-9]"), "", true);
    TrimFilter trimFilter = new TrimFilter(prFilter);
    return new TokenStreamComponents(source, trimFilter);
}
```

...

```
@KeywordSearch
@Analyzer(impl = com.jjkane.common.search.analyzer.PhoneNumberAnalyzer.class)
@Field(name = "phone", index = org.hibernate.search.annotations.Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
public String getPhone() {
    return this.phone;

}
```

This may just be ignorance on my part in attempting to do this... From all the documentation, it seems like I am on the right track, but the query never matches unless I submit (555)555-5555 as an exact match to what was in my db. If I put in 5555555555, I get nothing...

Comment: Your code seems correct... Maybe you could show us how you query the index? You could also try to define your analyzer differently, as a [named analyzer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-named-analyzers), just to see if you have the same problem. Also, take care to reindex your whole database before you test your analyzer!

Comment: What is the "@KeywordSearch" annotation?

Comment: @KeywordSearch is just a custom annotation... I'm just saving an object to get it to reindex. that should be ok. Testing by rebuilding the entire index can take an hour or more in my case.

Comment: Got it. Be aware there also is FullTextSession#index(T) and/or FullTextEntityManager.index(T) to force the reindexing a specific entity.

Comment: Awesome thanks for reminding... I am noticing my analyzer isn't getting called on index for that field. Should it store the values as 5555555555 as it saves?

Comment: If I slide the analyzer into the @Field it works just fine... Not sure why it doesn't work as a method annotatation